# Laravel select query returning array

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-5, laravel-4

My select query is returning an array... but I would like for it to return an object

PHP:

```
$language = DB::select(select query here);
```

I tried adding `->get()` after but it seems that I can't add that to an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It's supposed to return an array of stdClass objects, no need for `->get` when usind `DB:select` to run raw MySql code.

If you are selecting a row with the raw sql, then you can access the object for that row as `$language[0]`, else you have to loop through it.

Answer (score 2):

`->get()` returns a collection. If you just want to get one object, use `->first()` instead.

See the query [builder documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results) under "Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table" for more details.